# NSMutableAttributeString not working in iOS 10.0 in UIAlertController

Tags: ios10, uialertcontroller, nsmutableattributedstring

Hello am using NSMutableAttributedString to show different fonts but with same size in UIAlertController, the problem here is it showing two different fonts which is correct but it also showing two different sizes.Here is my code

```
 UIFont *regularFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:11.0];
UIFont *boldFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:11.0];

UIAlertController *alertObj = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:messageStr preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

NSMutableAttributedString *attMessage = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:messageStr];
[attMessage addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:regularFont range:NSRangeFromString(messageStr)];
[attMessage addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:boldFont range:NSMakeRange(25, 6)];
[attMessage addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:boldFont range:NSMakeRange(35, 15)];

[alertObj setValue:attMessage forKey:@"attributedMessage"];
```

Result can be match.Any help would be appreciated

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't "hack" the UIAlertController. Use a custom one.

Comment: In your range give it like, NSMakeRange(6, 25) and NSMakeRange(15, 35).  @Nisar Ahmad

Comment: Problem is not with Range . . . @KAR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `attributedMessage` property is not public, using it is a good way to get your app rejected at the review. If you *really* need to style the dialogue and distribute the app on the App Store, I think you should build your own component to display the pop-up.